# Header file not found in Bridging Header

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode9, bridging-header

I've looked through a number posts and cannot find a solution to this problem.

I installed the [MMLanScan](https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan) Objective C library into in my pod file successfully.

Then I created a bridging header file in my project directory

```
#ifndef BridingHeader_h
#define BridingHeader_h

#import "MMLANScanner.h"
#import "LANProperties.h"
#import "PingOperation.h"
#import "MMLANScanner.h"
#import "MACOperation.h"
#import "MacFinder.h"
#import "MMDevice.h"

#endif
```

I also set the header file path in my project's compiler settings

[image]

But when I build my app, I get two compile time errors

error 1:

> `MMLANScanner.h` file not found

error 2:

> Failed to emit precompiled header `/Users/my user name/Library/Developer/Xcode/Derived Data/My Project Name...

Both these errors disappear when I delete my imports from the bridging header file.

Any clues how to compile this library would be appreciated.

**edit**

So the required .h files appear to be in my pod directory, so not sure why I get these errors

[image]

Comment: There are a few possibilities, but start with ensuring the path to the bridging header is correct.  Also, when working with Cocopods remember to work with (and open the project with) the Workspace.

Comment: @BonanzaDriver Thanks, I just ended up added the relative folder path to the import and it worked!

Comment: You might be able to even skip adding the folder `MMLanScan` if you use the `User header search paths` in the target `Build Settings` tab.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was as simple as adding the relative folder path to the header file imports

```
#ifndef BridingHeader_h
#define BridingHeader_h

#import "MMLanScan/MMLANScanner.h"
#import "MMLanScan/LANProperties.h"
#import "MMLanScan/PingOperation.h"
#import "MMLanScan/MMLANScanner.h"
#import "MMLanScan/MACOperation.h"
#import "MMLanScan/MacFinder.h"
#import "MMLanScan/MMDevice.h"

#endif
```

not

```
#ifndef BridingHeader_h
#define BridingHeader_h

#import "MMLANScanner.h"
#import "LANProperties.h"
#import "PingOperation.h"
#import "MMLANScanner.h"
#import "MACOperation.h"
#import "MacFinder.h"
#import "MMDevice.h"

#endif
```